# Angular 7 mat-datepicker returns moment but need a Date

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular7, angular-moment

My `mat-datepicker` returns a Moment instead of a Date, but I need a Date to work with. In app.module I have

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it' },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'it' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentUtcDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useValue: getItalianPaginatorIntl() }
```

where `MY_FORMATS` is

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
  },
};
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are providing `MomentUtcDateAdapter`as the DateAdapter. If you remove this provider it should work just as you expect.